# Concurrency with non-thread safe resources

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, concurrency

I have a multi-threaded application that implements `async` methods. The application utilizes resources that are not thread safe, and needs to be used on a single thread. The worker thread is guarded like this

```
private void EnsureWorkerIsRunning()
{
    // first try without lock
    if (_processingRequests)
    {
        return;
    }
    lock (_processLock)
    {
        // try again without lock
        if (_processingRequests)
        {
            return;
        }
        _processingRequests = true;
        DoWork();
        _processingRequests = false;
    }
}
```

That is

1. Check if (the `bool`) `_processingRequests` is `true` without any lock. If it is processing requests, return and be confident that the worker is running.
2. If `_processingRequests` is `false`, continue to the `lock` statement, only allowing one thread to enter at a time. The first thread that enters the block set's `_processingRequests` to `true` and starts the worker. Any subsequent threads that enter the `lock` block will bail, since `_processingRequests` are now `true`.

Adding a `lock` directly introduces a performance hit that is not acceptable.

I'm looking for a more elegant way to achieve the same thing without affecting the performance. Any ideas?

Comment: Thread1 enters `DoWork` and Thread2 is blocked by `lock` after that. My question is: after thread1 exits the lock, does thread2 have to run `DoWork` again in your scenario?

Comment: How did you measure this unacceptable performance hit?

Comment: If a lock is too slow then there's something wrong with DoWork().  It does not do enough work.  And then it doesn't make sense anymore to run it on a worker thread.

Comment: This can never work because _processingRequests will appear true right before it becomes false. This method does not actually ensure that a worker is running when the method exits.

Comment: @acelent: I've run the code with nested tasks (20x outer tasks, 50'000x inner tasks) under a stopwatch.

Comment: @HansPassant @urs @Danny Chen `DoWork()` dequeues "work items" from a `ConcurrentDictionary` that all threads are able to enqueue items to. The worker does this until the queue is empty, and then stops. This is why we need to ensure that the worker is running.

Comment: From the accepted answer (using `Monitor.TryEnter` instead of `lock`), the issue was not raw performance, but blocking vs. non-blocking behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The technique you are using is called [Double-checked locking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking) and is perfectly fine approach to use, where suitable. It's widely used and it's nothing to do with elegance, because it's main purpose is to reduce the performance degradation when entering `lock` statement each time, with additional checking for a condition without a lock.

However in your particular case it's more suitable to use just `Monitor.TryEnter`, which returns `false` if some thread has already acquired the lock.

Also, a [blog post](http://blog.tsunanet.net/2010/11/how-long-does-it-take-to-make-context.html) about the impact of processor's context switches, that double-checked locking avoids where unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

`bool _processingRequests` with additional `lock(_processLock)` is a nonsense.

Use proper synchronization, e.g. [`Monitor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.monitor(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
object _processLock = new object();

// acquiring lock,
if(Monitor.TryEnter(_processLock)) // if already acquired - exit immediately(return false)
    try
    {
        ...
    }
    finally { Monitor.Exit(_processLock); }
```

This will either do job or, if `_processLock` is already *occupied*, don't do (seems you want that behavior), no need to check for anything.

Comment: Thanks - this helped!